# Name not a valid identifier

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am making a VB.NET Windows app, using DataGridView. I am trying to add and name my columns. I try to name the first column Step, and it gives me an error  `'Step' is not a valid identifier`. If I type Name it does not give me an error. Why can't I name this column Step?

[image]

Comment: Name is not what is displayed; Header text is. Name is how you would refer to the column in code. Maybe colStep.

Answer (score 1):

`Step` is a VB keyword, so you can't use it as the name of a column because the designer will try to generate a field with that name.  You should never encounter such an issue anyway, because `Step` is a bad name even if it was allowed.  If someone was to see that name in code they would have no idea what it was actually for.  At the very least, use `StepColumn`.  You could certainly change the header text to "Step".